# Powershell #Requires path/to/Name.exe

Tags: powershell, require

I would like to prevent my script from running if 'foobar.exe' is not in the correct location. I.E.  'C:\path\to\Foobar.exe'

I have tried `#Requires -Assembly 'path\to\Foobar.exe'` but it throws an error
[image: Error]
The error is unclear as to how to resolve this.

If I can't use `#Requires` is there a different way to prevent the script from running if its 'Foobar.exe' is not in `path\to`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this at the start of the script?

```
If (-not (Test-Path -Path 'C:\Path\To\foo.exe')) {
    Throw "Cannot find 'C:\Path\To\foo.exe'"
}
```